# Can i add/update images to existing rows in Mysql using update statement?, if yes what is the syntax?

Tags: mysql

Can I add/update images to newly added column in MySQL using UPDATE statement? If yes, what is the syntax ?

I want to insert images in the newly added column but in the existing fields not new fields, which is why I can't use insert statement.

NOTE: I am using Phpmyadmin.

Here is an image of what I exactly want 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1upP.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the image column must be defined as a **BLOB** column. Then, you have to convert your image to binary data. In PHP, it can be done using `file_get_contents()` function.

Then, you can insert / update the image data to database using normal SQL statements.

```
$image_data = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])); // addslashes() function converts any special character in raw image data to processable character for the db
$sql = "update TABLE_NAME set IMAGE_COLUMN = ".$image_data." where ID = ".$row_id;
```

You can see detailed example of this operation (and its related operations) [here](http://www.codingcage.com/2016/02/upload-insert-update-delete-image-using.html).

Hope that it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replay.. but isn't there any way to do it using SQL queries ? because actually i didn't even start to design and develop the website yet and i cant use PHP, i am preparing the database right now.

Comment: You have to convert your image data to binary data - no matter how you want to insert the image in db (by php or by raw sql). If you want to insert the image using raw sql, then after converting your image to binary data and copying that data to clipboard, you can use the following sql: `update TABLE_NAME set IMAGE_COLUMN = *paste your image binary data here* where ID = ROW_ID`

Comment: sounds good, but can you tell me how to change the image to binary data ? is there programs or websites that do this ?

Comment: You can try to use [this tool](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hexdump.htm) - see if it works for you.

Comment: Personally, I didn't have to use such tools for this kind of work, as I used php for the whole operation.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. 
i will do my search on this or may be i will consider starting to developing my website first. :)